# Association Rule Mining on Multivariate Time Series

Tags: r, weka, rweka

I have a data set which contains multiple variables varying with time. I want to run a association mining algorithm to mine the variables whose patterns change at the same time.It seems there is something on Temporal Association Mining but couldn't find any package in this. Neither is the topic mentioned in the CRAN Task Views.

Comment: The changes over time involve repeated patterns?

Comment: @Pj_ not sure, but visually it seems so. I need to find automated way of getting the pattern matching done since the variables inmy data set are around 1300 +

Comment: Have you checked AruleSequence? http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/arulesSequences/arulesSequences.pdf